# Response to a PATCH request

Tags: rest, http, django-rest-framework, api-design

Suppose I have an endpoint `/api/todos` and I make a `PATCH` request to change one of the todos. Does it ever make sense for my `PATCH` request to have in the response body the list of all of the todos?

Is there any specification that I can read about this?

I have talked to some developers and the general consensus is that the `PATCH` method should only return the changed entry. I agree with this point but am looking for documentation detailing this.

Comment: https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7240.html#return might be of interest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The RFC is [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.txt).

But it doesn't really specify anything. Here's an example from it:

```
   Successful PATCH response to existing text file:

   HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
   Content-Location: /file.txt
   ETag: "e0023aa4f"

   The 204 response code is used because the response does not carry a
   message body (which a response with the 200 code would have).  Note
   that other success codes could be used as well.
```

So you can implement it however you wish. Responding with just the changed entry would be more inline with how other methods (PUT, DELETE, etc.) are usually handled, so I would do it that way.

Answer (score 5):

So when you want to provide a RESTfull api `/api/todos` represents a ressource where every todo has an separate id. Here you would patch e.g. to `/api/todos/4' to update the todo with the id 4.
The usual behaviour here would be to responde with either a 204 Status Code or with the updated object to save another request to get the updated todo.

If your todo's aren't separate objects with id's they are propably a list of items and should be returned all at once.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the Google API AIPs for most of my api development.

https://google.aip.dev/134

Small excerpt from AIP 134 which is about updates and PATCH.

- The response message **must** be the resource itself.
- The response **should** include the fully-populated resource, and **must** include any fields that were sent and included in the update mask unless they are input only (see AIP-203).